# Javascript: how to programmatically kill an alert after X seconds

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

When asking for permission for geolocation the user gets a popup window asking for geolocation permission.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

Lets say the user doesn't respond after 5 seconds, I would like to "force the errorCallback".
How would I do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition), the third argument to `getCurrentPosition()` is an options object that allows you to specify a timeout value.

The documentation specifies that the timeout value is the max time allowed to wait for the GPS position, so you'd have to test it to see if it also includes the time waiting for the user to respond to a permission prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it's more or less up to the browser how to handle the fact that the user is not replying on the question about permission.

Anyhow, a workaround could be a redirect after a given time:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My page</h1>

        <script>
            var userdidnothing=false;

            function TimeoutHandler() {
                if (!userdidnothing) {
                    window.location.href="http://www.yoursecondpage.com";
                }
            }

            setTimeout("TimeoutHandler();",5000);

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function() { 
                    userdidnothing=true;
                    alert("SUCCESS");
                }, 
                function() {
                    alert("ERROR");
                });
            }
        </script>

        Geolocation feature is helpful, if you need to know where you are...
    </body>
 </html>
```